# Generage hash/checksum for values returned

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to implement a stored procedure which can create a checksum for a number of rows. To be more precise, when calling a stored procedure I want to create a single checksum value for all the rows returned. Thus, when the stored procedure is called again another time, I want to make sure the generate checksum matches with the previous generated value. This will be used for unit testing. I was in the process of implementing unit testing using Visual Studio and came across this checksum feature as well.

Has anyone implemented such a feature before?

Comment: You could create a checksum for each row but how could you "create it for all the rows"? Also, note that checksum in cases may return the same value for 2 different rows.

Comment: I think [CHECKSUM_AGG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188920.aspx) may be helpful here

Comment: I'm looking at HASHBYTES at the moment, but it looks like I have to create a value hashbyte for each row